# Blockchain.info wallet/receive API callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, payment, blockchain

So for the past many many hours I've been trying to implement blockchains receive/wallet api to my node.js app.

There's two ways which you can implement this:
 1. Use the receive  api which is documented here: https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive
 2. Use the wallet api which is documented here:
 https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api

Now here's my issue:
I got the receive api (1) to work, however the transactions are very very very slow(1+ hour), and the callbacks likewise if they even reach. Other than that it does what i need it to: pass some custom paramaters into the callback url such as customer_id, price, amount_purchased. But due to the waiting time I can't use this method and I wish to implement the wallet api (2):

The wallet api works a bit different you DON'T specify a callback url, instead you set one in your account which looks like this -> 
[image: d]
The way I pass in the mentioned custom variables is afaik through the label method, **here's the my question:**
How do i retrieve this label because if I do something like this:
  [image: n]
Then the callback url receives the price however it's of course undefined.
**Second question is:** 
How do I pass in multiple values into the label, something like formatting it like this:
{'user_id': userId, 'order_amount': amount, 'order_price': price}
?

I've tried writing to blockchain.info themselves, i received some answers about reading their docs @ https://docs.blockchain.info
Then when i asked into details about how to receive the actual labels, there was dead silence. So now I'm asking you guys :)

Hope some people out there can help me with this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their documentation there will always be the parameters 'value', 'transaction_hash', 'input_address' and 'confirmations' as well as any constants you specify as parameters in the URL already. 
The 'value' parameter appears to be what you expected as price.

You cannot give the parameters custom names though.

Comment: Yeah agreed, but I don't want constant values, as customer_id, price and order amount changes for each order.

How would i enter those changing values into the label ?

Comment: This callback doesn't seem to be connected to any items, it just informs you when funds are transferred to or from your wallet. So you'd have to do the mapping on your server.

Comment: Alright, thanks so much, do you have some documentation I could read about mapping it on my server?

Comment: Well, you could create a wallet address for each order, keep the order+address pair on the server and once your callback is called you can check for the order+address pair which has the address provided by the 'input_address' parameter.

Comment: hmm yeah I'm at little confused as to excactly how i'll pull this off, but i'll give it a try, thanks so much for your time sir. :)

Comment: I would be able to insert it into a db, then check it on callback, I'm a little scared that it will be slow though. And would like to keep that information on my server, so I'm not sure

Comment: Depends on the db, but since you don't seem to have sub-second response-time requirements (atleast not for reacting when a payment was made), using a db should be fine.

Comment: Assuming that you generate addresses for every transaction -  You can register a custom callback while requesting a receive address for your wallet. I would suggest you to form your callback with identifiers based on your transaction or request ... <baseurl>/receive/bitcoin/<userid>/<other-identifiers>